# JSP/Servlet can't get text from textarea

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm trying to upload to a database a photo with a description. Basically I've managed to upload the photo, but the description (comment) is always set as null.

index.jsp contains a form with a file input and a textarea

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="2" id="comment" name="comment" placeholder="Write something"></textarea>
```

Servlet code:

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String comment = request.getParameter("comment");

    if(ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)){
        try {

            List<FileItem> multiparts = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);

            for(FileItem item : multiparts){
                if(!item.isFormField()){
                    String name = new File(item.getName()).getName();
                    item.write( new File(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY + File.separator + name));
                    // till now, the photo is being saved in a folder
                    // method addPhoto uploads this photo in database
                    // this method works OK
                    addPhoto((int) request.getSession().getAttribute("id"), UPLOAD_DIRECTORY + File.separator + name , comment);
                }
            }

           request.setAttribute("message", "File Uploaded Successfully");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
           request.setAttribute("message", "File Upload Failed due to " + ex);
        }          
    }
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

If anyone could help me, how can I set the description of photo in database?

Comment: Can u send us your form code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the request is encoded as "multipart/form-data", you have to get the parameters after the request is parsed. In your code, can you try

```
for(FileItem item : multiparts){
 if(!item.isFormField()){
   // the logic you already have now
 } else {
   if ("comment".equals(item.getFieldName())) {
        String comment = item.getString();
    // Whatever you have to do with the comment
   }
 }
}
```